# Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК (Windows 10)

Tags: c, mingw, makefile

Недавно перешел с MinGW на MinGW-w64. Все установил, поставил все пути в ide Code::block. Делаю тестовую программу Hello World, компилирую - на экране пустота. Захожу в папку, где лежит бинарник проекта. Запускаю, и вин 10 выдает - Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК. Как быть? Уже голову сломал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бинарник появился, значит компиляция прошла успешно и проблема в **запуске** вашего приложения.

Проблема запуска приложения может быть связана с отсутствием зависимых библиотек в папке с бинарником или в `PATH` или [ещё из-за кучи причин](http://temowind.ru/vse-o-windows-10/nevozmozhno-zapustit-eto-prilozhenie-na-vashem-pk/).

Чтобы просмотреть, от каких библиотек зависит ваш `exe`, можно воспользоваться специальной утилитой [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) или Lister плагином для TotalCommander:

[image: Lister плагин]

Как видно из скриншота, программа скомпилирована с зависимостью от runtime библиотеки MinGW `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` и месторасположение этой библиотеки неизвестно (на самом деле, она лежит в папке `\mingw-w64\mingw32\bin\`).

Чтобы решить эту проблему, надо либо добавить в `PATH` путь к зависимой библиотеке, либо положить её рядом с `exe` (и все библиотеки, от которых она зависит), либо при компиляции проекта указать, чтобы она линковалась статически (конкретно, для статической линковки `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` нужно в настройках проекта добавить флаг линковщику: `-static-libgcc`).

---

**Upd:** Как выяснилось из комментариев, была попытка запустить 64-х битный бинарник на 32-х битной системе. Отсюда следует вывод, что нужно внимательно смотреть, под какую платформу вы собираете своё приложение. У готового бинарника, так же можно выяснить, какой он разрядности (32/64 бит). Информация об этом находится в [PE заголовках](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) и есть программы, для просмотра этих заголовков (например, PE Explorer или тот же Lister плагин для TC):

[image: Lister плагин]

Comment: Я добавил -static-libgcc но к сожалению не помогло... Вес файла увеличился, да. Но все та же ошибка - Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем ПК

Comment: @Corle Дополните вопрос кодом, который вы компилируете. Приведите логи сборки, укажите разрядность системы и бинарника. Попробуйте запустить бинарник на другой версии Windows, на другом компьютере или в виртуальной машине. Попробуйте рекомендации по ссылке, которую я давал в ответе ([эту](http://temowind.ru/vse-o-windows-10/nevozmozhno-zapustit-eto-prilozhenie-na-vashem-pk/)). Выложите свой бинарник на обменник и дайте ссылку, чтобы мы могли проверить его работоспособность у себя.

Comment: http://rgho.st/7DD72p5fQ вот сам проект, логи там же. Буду очень признателен если поможете! Кстати забавно то, что если запустить бинарник из под wine в linux - он работает

Comment: @Corle по вашей ссылке невозможно ничего скачать.

Comment: извините, вот - http://dropmefiles.com/3yy0z

Comment: @Corle ваш бинарник у меня отлично запускается (на Win8.1 x64). Он 64-х битный, возможно, ваша Windows 10 32-х битная, и она, естественно, не сможет его запустить.

Comment: Так, понял. Весело получилось...у меня система 32-х битная, компилятор тоже скачал для 32х битной системы...вышел 64битный бинарник. Как-то можно поправить?

Comment: @Corle В настройках Code::Blocks укажите правильный компилятор. Сейчас там указан `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`, а должен быть `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`.

Comment: Сейчас поставлю, один момент ( заранее простите если время отнимаю :) )